# Multicore in Windows: where to go after all threads are finished?

Tags: windows, multithreading, nasm, x86-64

I am writing code in NASM (64 bit) in Windows to run four simultaneous threads (each assigned to a separate core) on a four-core Windows x86-64 machine.  Below is my thread instantiation code.  Each thread calls the same program.

The code is shown below in the exact sequence it appears in the source file (without the .data section, and some code abbreviated).  Each thread (core) executes Test_Function across a large array.  The first core starts at data element zero, the second core starts at 1, the third core starts at 2, the fourth core starts at 3, and each core increments by four (e.g., 0, 4, 8, 12).  When finished, Test_Function exits at label_899.  They write their results to the corresponding locations in a shared array created with malloc.

My question is:  where do I go after all threads are finished at label_899?  Do the threads then return to the final line of ThreadStart (after jl label_0), where cleanup is performed?  Test_Function exits with ret, so I assume that returns control to the thread instantiation section (ThreadStart).

Unfortunately, all of the information I have read on this focuses on the creation of a single thread.  Some resources talk about thread synchronization while running, but I have found nothing directly relevant about what happens after all threads are finished.

Thanks for any help.  I would post a complete example, but I don't know yet how to complete it, which is my question.

```
ThreadStart:

mov rbp,rsp ; preserve caller's stack frame
mov rdi,ThreadInfo ; two element array
sub rsp,32 ; Shadow space

label_0:

mov rax,StartByte
mov [rdi],rax ; 0, 8, 16, or 24
mov rax,[JumpCount]
mov [rdi+8],rax ; number of cores (4 in this example)

push 0 ; Creation flags, start immediately (may want to delay until all created)
push 0 ; ThreadID

mov rcx,0               ; lpThreadAttributes (Security Attributes)
mov rdx,0               ; dwStackSize
mov r8,Test_Function    ; lpStartAddress (function pointer)
mov r9,rdi              ; lpParameter

call CreateThread

mov rax,8
add [StartByte],rax

mov rax,[TreadCount]
add rax,1
mov [TreadCount],rax
cmp rax,4
jl label_0

[ Code to do cleanup if needed after the four threads finish ]

mov rsp,rbp

jmp final_out
;______

Test_Function:

xor rcx,rcx
mov [loop_counter_401],rcx
label_401:
lea rdi,[rel numbers_ptr]
mov rbp,qword [rdi] ; Pointer
mov rcx,[loop_counter_401]
mov rax,[numbers_length]
cmp rcx,rax
jge label_899
movsd xmm0,qword[rbp+rcx]
movsd [num_float],xmm0
add rcx,32 ;8 -- add 32 for four loops, not 8
mov [loop_counter_401],rcx

[ MORE CODE]

jmp label_401

label_899:

ret
;______

final_out:
mov rdi,Return_Pointer_Array
mov rax,r15
mov [rdi+0],rax
mov rax,r14
mov [rdi+8],rax
mov rax,rdi
ret
```

Update 030119

Following is the code that creates threads as it is now.  Earlier I though it failed at CreateThread, but it does not.  It fails now due to a problem with the code I call, and I am debugging it now.  I will post back with my results.  The failure may be in how I wrote the code for WaitForMultipleObjects.

Shown is the thread instantiation code, not the code called by the threads.

```
mov rdi,ThreadInfo
mov rax,StartByte
mov [rdi+8],rax     ; 0, 8, 16, or 24

; _____
; Create Threads

mov rcx,0               ; lpThreadAttributes (Security Attributes)
mov rdx,0               ; dwStackSize
mov r8,Test_Function        ; lpStartAddress (function pointer)
mov rax,rdi
mov r9,rax              ; lpParameter (array of data passed to each core)

mov rax,0
mov [rsp+40],rax            ; use default creation flags
mov rax,[ThreadCount]
mov [rsp+32],rax            ; ThreadID

call CreateThread

; Move the handle into ThreadHandles array (returned in rax)
mov rdi,ThreadHandles
mov rcx,[StartByte]
mov [rdi+rcx],rax

mov rax,8
add [StartByte],rax

mov rax,[ThreadCount]
add rax,1
mov [ThreadCount],rax
cmp rax,4
jl label_0

; _____
; Wait

mov rcx,rax         ; number of handles
mov rdx,ThreadHandles       ; pointer to handles array
mov r8,1                ; wait for all threads to complete
mov r9,1000         ; milliseconds to wait

call WaitForMultipleObjects

; _____

;[ Code to do cleanup if needed after the four threads finish ]

mov rsp,rbp

jmp label_900
```

Comment: When a thread returns from the starting function, the thread is destroyed. Your main thread should wait at the cleanup point for all the threads to exit by calling WaitForSingleObject or WaitForMultipleObjects using the thread handles returned by CreateThread.

Comment: Here is an example from Microsoft. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/ProcThread/creating-threads

Comment: Thanks, prl.  I have been working on this, and I had just come to the same conclusion, so your message is very helpful.  According to MSoft "The calling thread uses the WaitForMultipleObjects function to persist until all worker threads have terminated."  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/ProcThread/creating-threads

Comment: Followup question -- do I store the thread handles from CreateThread in a separate array, or is there another way to access them on completion?  Also, how does the main thread wait at the cleanup point?  Does that happen by default?

Comment: I think you can get the thread handle from the thread id, but it's better just to store the handle values returned by CreateThread. (Also you pass NULL for pThreadId, so you don't have that value anyway.)

Comment: At the moment NULL is a placeholder.  I'll replace that.

Comment: The comments on the 5th and 6th parameters are reversed. Creation flags is the 5th parameter and pThreadId is the 6th parameter.

Comment: At the point of the call, there needs to be 32 bytes of space between the stack pointer and the 5th parameter. You need to put flags at [rsp+0x20] and pthreadid at [rsp+28].

Comment: Up toward the top I have sub rsp,32 -- do you mean it should go elsewhere?  It can't go into the creation loop or I'll subtract 32 four times.  It looks like you're advising that the two push instructions should be rsp-relative instead??

Comment: My suggestion is to subtract 56 bytes from rsp on entry to the function and not change rsp after that. (i.e., no pushes)

Comment: I see your point.  I need extra space for the two pushes, but you specify an extra 24 (three pushes?).

Comment: You'll need more space to store the handles and the thread ids, too.

Comment: Great.  I'm not supposed to say thanks, but I will anyway.  Thanks.

Comment: The stack is supposed to be 16-byte aligned before calling any function, so you have to subtract an odd multiple of 8 (since the call itself pushes the 8-byte RIP).

Comment: At the top (not shown here) I begin the program with align=16.  Should I use an NOP to align?

Comment: That aligns the code. The stack needs to be aligned at the entry to every function by subtracting 8 or n×16+8 from RSP.

Comment: Thanks again.  I do that with malloc.

Comment: If you want to, you could post your code again in an answer after you make the changes we discussed, and I can look at it again. (Or you could add it as an addendum to the question, but don't remove the original code from the question.)

Comment: I can post it as an answer tomorrow.  Thanks for the offer, I really appreciate it .

Comment: You can also use a semaphore to wait for all thread to finish, this will handle visibility and ordering for you. To keep you code symmetric you can pass one more Boolean parameter to each thread, when true the thread when finished will wait on the semaphore and then do the aftermath work.

Comment: I posted an update above.  It fails at the call to CreateThread.  Please see the update for details.  @Margaret Bloom - I will also try a semaphore separately to see which works best.  Thanks very much for any help.

Comment: Please disregard my update for now.  I have worked beyond that point and I don't have any new questions yet.  I will post a more complete question (or answer) when I know more.  Thanks.

Comment: I just posted a new question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54963179/multicore-in-nasm-windows-lpparameter-data-are-wrong-on-entry.  The issues have evolved since I posted this question.