# Multicore in NASM Windows: lpParameter data are wrong on entry

Tags: windows, multithreading, assembly, nasm, x86-64

I have code in NASM (64 bit) in Windows to run four simultaneous threads (each assigned to a separate core) on a four-core Windows x86-64 machine.

The lpParameter is passed in r9 (the data variables for each thread to pass to the function).  I am passing a pointer to an 8-element internal array (ThreadInfo) which contains variables to put into registers on entry to the function (variables are stored in registers for optimization purposes).  All four threads call the same function.

The problem is that on entry to the function, the data passed in the ThreadInfo array are all large (e.g. 128-bit) negative numbers.  The array contains 64-bit integers.  The array is read-only for each of the threads, so no thread can alter the memory.  I don't understand why the values should be wrong.  I tested them in the thread creation code and they are correct, but they return incorrect values when read from the called function.

Here is the test code showing the relevant parts.  Showing a reproducible example may not be possible due to the register values, but if this question can't be answered without that, then I can see if it's feasible to post a completely reproducible program.

```
Init_Cores_fn:
; EACH OF THE CORES CALLS Test_Function AND EXECUTES THE WHOLE PROGRAM.  
; WE PASS THE STARTING BYTE (0, 8, 16, 24) AND THE "STRIDE" = NUMBER OF CORES.  
; ON RETURN, WE SYNCHRONIZE ANY DATA.  ON ENTRY TO EACH CORE, SET THE REGISTERS

; Populate the ThreadInfo array with vars to pass
; ThreadInfo: length, startbyte, stride, vars into registers on entry to each core
mov rdi,ThreadInfo
mov rax,ThreadInfoLength
mov [rdi],rax
mov rax,[stride]
mov [rdi+16],rax    ; 8 x number of cores (32 in this example)
; Register Vars
mov [rdi+24],r15
mov [rdi+32],r14
mov [rdi+40],r13
mov [rdi+48],r12
mov [rdi+56],r10

mov rbp,rsp ; preserve caller's stack frame
sub rsp,56 ; Shadow space

; _____

label_0:

mov rdi,ThreadInfo
mov rax,[FirstByte]
mov [rdi+8],rax ; 0, 8, 16, or 24

; _____
; Create Threads

mov rcx,0               ; lpThreadAttributes (Security Attributes)
mov rdx,0               ; dwStackSize
mov r8,Test_Function    ; lpStartAddress (function pointer)
mov r9,ThreadInfo       ; lpParameter (array of data passed to each core)

mov rax,0
mov [rsp+40],rax            ; use default creation flags
mov rax,[ThreadCount]
mov [rsp+32],rax            ; ThreadID

call CreateThread

; Move the handle into ThreadHandles array (returned in rax)
mov rdi,ThreadHandles
mov rcx,[FirstByte]
mov [rdi+rcx],rax

mov rax,[FirstByte]
add rax,8
mov [FirstByte],rax

mov rax,[ThreadCount]
add rax,1
mov [ThreadCount],rax

mov rbx,4
cmp rax,rbx
jl label_0

; _____
; Wait

mov rcx,rax         ; number of handles
mov rdx,ThreadHandles       ; pointer to handles array
mov r8,1                ; wait for all threads to complete
mov r9,1000         ; milliseconds to wait

call WaitForMultipleObjects

; _____

;[ Code HERE to do cleanup if needed after the four threads finish ]

mov rsp,rbp
jmp label_900

; __________________
; The function for all threads to call

Test_Function:

; Populate registers
mov rdi,r9
mov rax,[rdi]
mov r15,[rdi+24]
mov rax,[rdi+8] ; start byte
mov r13,[rdi+40]
mov r12,[rdi+48]
mov r10,[rdi+56]
xor r11,r11
xor r9,r9
pxor xmm15,xmm15
pxor xmm15,xmm14
pxor xmm15,xmm13
```

The pointer is passed in r9, but on entry to Test_Function, the values are all large (e.g., 128-bit) negative values.  Why?

Thanks for any help on this.

Comment: Not sure why you're looking in `r9`. The first parameter is passed in `rcx`, which you well know because you put the first parameter in `rcx` when you called `CreateThread`.  Also, you are not preserving registers as required by the Windows calling convention. You also failed to declare unwind codes, which will make the system assume the functions are lightweight leaf functions, even though they aren't.

Comment: For thread instantiation in Windows, the lpParameter (the data pointer to use) is passed in r9.  rcx, rdx and r8 all contain other parameters here.

Comment: [ThreadProc callback function documented here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686736(v=vs.85).aspx). Observe that it has only one parameter, which therefore goes into `rcx` when your function is called.

Comment: The CreateThread function (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createthread) needs four parameters.  One of those parameters is the pointer to the data array for each thread to pass on entry.  That will be in r9.  For you comments, I'm not sure what you recommend to get the correct values in the array passed by each thread.  The array is populated by the register values before any thread instantiation.

Comment: Looking at your second comment, I changed from r9 to rcx and it appears to be the correct data now.  My confusion is that CreateThread gets four parameters, but it appears to transfer r9 to rcx on entry to the function called.  So on entry we read that pointer from rcx, not r9.  I think that's confusing and the documentation could be a little more clear on that point.  If I'm missing anything, please let me know.

Comment: The calling conventions apply to each function separately. lpParameter is the fourth parameter to CreateThread, so it goes in r9. It is the first parameter to ThreadProc, so it is passed in rcx.

Comment: This is documented in the [x64 calling conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/x64-calling-convention?view=vs-2017). First parameter goes in `rcx`, etc. `lpParameter` is the fourth parameter to `CreateThread` so it goes in `r9`. `lpParameter` is the first parameter to `ThreadProc` so it goes in `rcx`.

Comment: I see that now, but I think it's a pretty subtle detail.  Thanks very much to both of you for your help on this.

Comment: I think you might be better off learning assembly language in a simpler setting, rather than trying to learn assembly language at the same time as learning about ABI conventions. (You still need to add unwind codes in order to conform with the Windows x64 calling convention. Also, you did not keep the stack on an 8-byte boundary.)

Comment: The problem isn't my knowledge of NASM, it's my knowledge of the Windows ABI in this situation.  But I really appreciate your comments.

Comment: @RaymondChen: The stack needs to be 16-byte aligned before a `call`, not just 8, for Windows x64 (same as x86-64 System V).  I think the OP is maintaining 8-byte alignment; I don't see any 16-bit `push`/`pop` or add/sub of RSP with a non-multiple of 8.  Perhaps you meant to say *that* wasn't sufficient, and you do need 16-byte?

Comment: @RaymondChen -- I did not unwind by adding back to rsp, instead I passed rbp back to rsp at the end, in the line "mov rsp,rbp" right before jmp label_900 (where the function exits).  I think that's why you may have missed it.   I preserved rsp in rbp on entry at the top.

Comment: Oops, sorry about the stack misalignment false alarm. But you are trashing registers which are required to be preserved.

Comment: rcx, rdx, r8 and r9 (used in the call) are volatile and do not need to be preserved.  Which registers do you mean?  Also, I just noticed that my first thread is not executing (I tested it) while threads 2-4 are.  Do you have any thoughts on that?  Could that be a side effect of WaitForMultipleObjects?

Comment: (1) You don't save rbp before overwriting it.  (2) The flags and thread Id parameters to CreateThread are reversed. (3) lpThreadId is a pointer. You are passing a small integer. (It is an out parameter.)

Comment: Since you don't use rsp or rbp in the function, you can just subtract 56 from rsp at the beginning and add 56 at the end and not change rbp at all. If you want to use rbp to set up a traditional stack frame, then use `push rbp; mov rbp, rsp; sub rsp, 48` and at the end, `mov rsp, rbp; pop rbp`.

Comment: @prl, I think your last two comments address my question of the failure of the first thread to execute, but your suggestions haven't changed that.  I just posted a new question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54972015/multicore-in-nasm-windows-threads-execute-randomly to fully describe the problem.  Thanks.